# XMPPConnection cannot connect again after idle for some time

Tags: android, asmack

I am using asmack to develop a `xmpp` android app which connects to `gtalk.google.com` (copy from GSMSTalk).

There is a very interesting issue and I cannot resolve it.

I can connect to the gtalk server using the `WiFi` or `3G` data without problem. The situation is it cannot connect again after the WiFi is disconnected and I have let the phone idle for some time.

For example.

- I have connected to the gtalk.google.com using `WiFi` at home.
- I go to work, of course, the WiFi is not available. I switch to 3G data, start the app and try to connect again. But it doesn't connect anymore, It just stop at connection.connect();
- I need to kill the app, and it can then connect again.
- I have done a lot of testing, it only happens if I let the phone idle for more than ~10 mins after losing the WiFi connection.
- For example, I go out for a short walk (the `WiFi` is disconnected), if I switch to `3G` data within ~5mins, I can still connect again.

I would appreciate it if anyone can give me some idea what's happening?

Regards,
Cow.

Comment: Q: Are you sure conncetion.connect(); is called again?

Since I expect that you simply have an error where it just isn't getting called again. Otherwise, check if the connection is properly closed before starting a new one.

Comment: According to the log, it calls the connection.connect(), and then stuck there.

Comment: Also, the same code and same steps. It works if I reconnect it within 5 mins.